# Why is std::is_pod deprecated in C++20?

Tags: c++, type-traits, standard-layout, trivially-copyable

`std::is_pod` has been deprecated in C++20.
What's the reason for this choice? What should I use in place of `std::is_pod` to know if a type is actually a POD?

Comment: See also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0767r1.html and US 101 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0488r0.pdf

Comment: Why do you want to know if a type is POD?

Comment: @MarcGlisse A question about changes in the standard or a trait like this doesn't necessarily mean that I want to use that feature. I found the _deprecated_ note while googling and I was just curious to know why it was deprecated.

Comment: My question was actually an indirect answer: it was removed because (roughly) there is no reason to ask if a type is POD.

Comment: I would use it for a `static_assert` to ensure no one touches structs that should be shared with C code.

Comment: @Mirko I find myself using it for that quite a lot as well, so this change is fairly disappointing.

Comment: This article is very helpful: https://andreasfertig.blog/2021/01/cpp20-aggregate-pod-trivial-type-standard-layout-class-what-is-what/

Answer (score 99, accepted):

POD is being replaced with two categories that give more nuances. The [c++ standard meeting in november 2017](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2017/11/20/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-albuquerque-november-2017/) had this to say about it:

> Deprecating the notion of “plain old data” (POD). It has been replaced with two more nuanced categories of types, “trivial” and “standard-layout”. “POD” is equivalent to “trivial and standard layout”, but for many code patterns, a narrower restriction to just “trivial” or just “standard layout” is appropriate; to encourage such precision, the notion of “POD” was therefore deprecated. The library trait is_pod has also been deprecated correspondingly.

For simple data types use the [`is_standard_layout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) function, for trivial data types (such as simple structs) use the [`is_trivial`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) function.

Comment: So, they add `remove_cvref` on one side, that is a composed trait, while on the other side they remove other composed traits? It seems insane. :-)

Comment: @skypjack One could argue pod is a misleading or often misused term

Comment: It seems to be trivial AND standard layout AND a clause involving being recursively POD. Is the recursive clause redundant?  Ie, is it guaranteed that `std::is_pod<T>{} == (std::is_trivial<T>{} && std::is_standard_layout<T>{})`?

Comment: @skypjack: The point of removing POD is that it no longer serves a purpose. The composition of "trivial" and "standard layout" doesn't actually mean anything in C++, and there's no reason why you would restrict an interface to POD rather than "trivial" or "standard layout" based on what you're actually doing with it. By contrast, removing "cvref" means something; the resulting type is an object type with no qualifiers.

Comment: @skypjack: "*Granted, but it's part of a library that contains an std::move utility that doesn't move anything.*" It shouldn't have been using `is_pod`; it should have used `is_trivially_copyable`.

Comment: I for one really appreciate this change. As a systems software programmer, "standard layout" was really what I cared about all along, and the requirement for PODs not having constructors made them not properly describe my common "structs with constructors" idiom. Previously I was forced to call those "pseudo-PODs". Cute, but it makes certain anime fans look funny at you when you talk about having pseudopods in your code.

Comment: Are `std::is_pod`,  `std::is_trivia` and  `std::is_standard_layout` compile-time? Because in algorithms, you might wish for a faster algorithm using memcpy() etc if C-layout compatible.

Comment: @SJHowe type_traits are all compile time just by the virtue of them being the traits of the __type__ (which only really exist at compile time).

Comment: MSVC claims `class S { S() = default; };` is POD but not trivial. I assume that's wrong?