# Can a POD type have a default move assignment operator with explicitly declared?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

Considering the following code:

```cpp
// in main.cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    A& operator=(const A&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_pod<A>::value);
    return 0;
}
```

You can see there's a default move assignment operator for `struct A`.

In **msvc(VS2017)**, with `cl /std:c++17 main.cpp`, I got a static assertion failure.

In **g++(MinGW-W64, 8.1.0)**, with `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp`, nothing went wrong.

However, if I comment out `A& operator=(A&&) = default;`, everything is ok in both two compilers.

So, can a POD type have a default move assignment operator with explicitly declared?

Comment: I don't see any reason why `A` should not be POD. It's defaulted move assignment operator is trivial. Note that [POD is going to become deprecated in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48225673/580083).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, POD type can have an explicitly declared default move assignment operator:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType

It was a bug in MSVC manifested up to compiler version 19.26, and fixed in 19.27. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c1o5fds3x