# Partial template specialization: template argument X is invalid

Tags: c++, c++17, template-specialization, default-template-argument

I want to partially specialize a class for when the first template parameter is not a POD-type. Here's what I came up with:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/736bovMsK)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
 
template <typename T, bool = std::is_pod<T>>
struct A
{
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "POD\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct A<T, false>
{
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Non-POD\n";
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    A<std::string> c;
    a.print();
    c.print();
}
```

However this doesn't compile and yields three types of errors (repeated for the string case):

```
<source>:4:43: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
    4 | template <typename T, bool = std::is_pod<T>>
      |                                           ^~
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:24:10: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   24 |     A<int> a;
      |          ^                ^
<source>:26:7: error: request for member 'print' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'int'
```

How would I do this? I already tried naming the default template argument (bool = ) but to no avail. Also adding all three parameters to the specialized template list doesn't help either.

Answer (score 5):

`is_pod<T>` itself is a class type that cannot be converted to `bool`, you should use `::value` to get its value

```
template <typename T, bool = std::is_pod<T>::value>
                                           // ^^^^^
struct A { };
```

It's worth noting that `is_pod` has been deprecated in C++20, for simple data types you should use `is_standard_layout`, and for trivial data types you should use the `is_trivial`.

See [Why is std::is_pod deprecated in C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225673/why-is-stdis-pod-deprecated-in-c20)

Comment: OMG thank you. Compiler warnings were not helpful at all in this case haha

Comment: In C++17, you have access to the less verbose version of `is_pod<T>::value` as `is_pod_v<T>`.